# How do I clear only a few specific objects from the workspace?

Tags: r

I would like to remove some data from the workspace. I know the "Clear All" button will remove all data. However, I would like to remove just certain data.

For example, I have these data frames in the data section:

```
data
data_1
data_2
data_3
```

I would like to remove `data_1`, `data_2` and `data_3`, while keeping `data`.

I tried `data_1 <- data_2 <- data_3 <- NULL`, which does remove the data (I think), but still keeps it in the workspace area, so it is not fully what I would like to do.

Answer (score 279, accepted):

You'll find the answer by typing `?rm`

```
rm(data_1, data_2, data_3)
```

Comment: For deleting all variables you can use `rm(list=ls())`.

Comment: but how can you do with the GUI, without the command line?  like in Revolution R

Comment: what if I want to remove all variables with names start with letter A, say 'A001', 'A002'.... 'A999'. I don't want to type so many variable names. Thanks!

Comment: Use @mbask's answer (just below):  `rm(list = ls()[grep("A", ls())])`

Answer (score 93):

A useful way to remove a whole set of named-alike objects:

```
rm(list = ls()[grep("^tmp", ls())])
```

thereby removing all objects whose name begins with the string "tmp".

Edit: Following Gsee's comment, making use of the `pattern` argument:

```
rm(list = ls(pattern = "^tmp"))
```

Edit: Answering Rafael comment, one way to retain only a subset of objects is to name the data you want to retain with a specific pattern. For example if you wanted to remove all objects whose name do not start with `paper` you would issue the following command:

```
rm(list = grep("^paper", ls(), value = TRUE, invert = TRUE))
```

Comment: `ls` accepts a `pattern` argument, so you can simplify that to `rm(list=ls(pattern="^tmp"))`

Comment: Separately, check out what happens when you use `value=TRUE` with `grep`... could save some typing.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to keep some few data and remove the others (a larger amount)? Cheers

Comment: Hi! And how could I keep in my R environment two different patterns? I tried "rm(list = grep("^paper" | "ObjectExample", ls(), value = TRUE, invert = TRUE))". Does anyone know?

Comment: You should include your regular expression into the `pattern` argument of `grep`: `rm(list = grep("^paper|ObjectExample", ls(), value = TRUE, invert = TRUE))`

Answer (score 15):

Following command will do

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
```

Comment: This will remove everything from the workspace, not just `data1`, `data2`, and `data3` (i.e. `data` will be removed too). Which is fine if that's what you want...

Comment: And what if one wants to remove only data, not functions, values or other objects in, say, the global environment?

Answer (score 15):

1. In RStudio, ensure the `Environment` tab is in `Grid` (not `List`) mode.
2. Tick the object(s) you want to remove from the environment.
3. Click the broom icon.

Comment: its popup should read 'Clear selected objects...'

Answer (score 10):

Use the following command

```
remove(list=c("data_1", "data_2", "data_3"))
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `apropos` function which is used to find the objects using partial name.

```
rm(list = apropos("data_"))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to remove one of a group of variables, then you can create a list and keep just the variable you need.  The rm function can be used to  remove all the variables apart from "data".  Here is the script:

```
0->data
1->data_1
2->data_2
3->data_3
#check variables in workspace
ls()
rm(list=setdiff(ls(), "data"))
#check remaining variables in workspace after deletion
ls()

#note: if you just use rm(list) then R will attempt to remove the "list" variable. 
list=setdiff(ls(), "data")
rm(list)
ls()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
paste0("data_",seq(1,3,1)) 
# makes multiple data.frame names with sequential number
rm(list=paste0("data_",seq(1,3,1))
# above code removes data_1~data_3
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using RStudio, please consider *never using the `rm(list = ls())` approach!** Instead, you should build your workflow around frequently employing the `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`F10` shortcut to restart your R session. This is the fastest way to both nuke the current set of user-defined variables AND to clear loaded packages, devices, etc. The reproducibility of your work will increase markedly by adopting this habit.

See [this excellent thread](https://community.rstudio.com/t/first-line-of-every-r-script/799?u=jessemaegan) on Rstudio community for (h/t @kierisi) for a more thorough discussion (the main gist is captured by what I've stated already).

I must admit my own first few years of R coding featured script after script starting with the `rm` "trick" -- I'm writing this answer as advice to anyone else who may be starting out their R careers.

*of course there are legitimate uses for this -- much like `attach` -- but beginning users will be much better served (IMO) crossing that bridge at a later date.

Answer (score 2):

Adding one more way, using ls() and remove()

ls() return a vector of character strings giving the names of the objects in the specified environment.

Create a list of objects you want to remove from the environment using ls() and then use remove() to remove it.

```
remove(list = ls()[ls() !=  "data"])
```

Answer (score 1):

To clear all data:

click on `Misc>Remove all objects`.

Your good to go.

To clear the console:

click on `edit>Clear console`.

No need for any code.

Comment: Though I had to do `Session> Clear Workspace...`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help as well

```
remove(list = c(ls()[!ls() %in% c("what", "to", "keep", "here")] ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use tidyverse

```
# to remove specific objects(s)
rm(list = ls() %>% str_subset("xxx")) 
# or to keep specific object(s)
rm(list = setdiff(ls(), ls() %>% str_subset("xxx")))
```