# Bigquery and R: Cost and where is the data stored?

Tags: r, google-bigquery

I'm using RStudio to run analysis on large datasets stored in BigQuery. The dataset is private and from a large retailer that shared the dataset with me via BigQuery to run the required analyses.
I used the bigrquery library to connect R to BigQuery, but couldn't find answers to the following two questions:

1) When I use R to run the analyses (e.g. first used SELECT to get the data and stored them in a data frame in R), is the data then somehow locally stored on my laptop? The company is concerned about confidentiality and probably doesn't want me to store the data locally but leave them in the cloud. But is it even possible to use R then?

2) My BigQuery free version has 1 TB/month for analyses. If I use select in R to get the data, it for instance tells me "18.1 gigabytes processed", but do I also use up my 1 TB if I run analyses on R instead of running queries on BigQuery? If it doesn't incur cost, then i'm wondering what the advantage is of running queries on BigQuery instead of in R, if the former might cost me money in the end?

Best
Jennifer

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Google's BigQuery is an entirely cloud based database.  This means that when you run a query or report on BigQuery, it happens in the cloud, and not locally (i.e. not in R).  This is not to say that your source data might be local; in fact, as you have seen you may upload a local data set from R.  But, the query would execute in the cloud, and then return the result set to R.

With regard to your other question, the source data in the BigQuery tables would remain in the cloud, and the only exposure to the data you would have locally would be the results of any query you might execute from R.  Obviously, if you ran `SELECT *` on every table, you could see all the data in a particular database.  So I'm not sure how much of a separation of concerns there would really be in your setup.

As for pricing, from the BigQuery [documentation on pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-overview):

> Query pricing refers to the cost of running your SQL commands and user-defined functions. BigQuery charges for queries by using one metric: the number of bytes processed. You are charged for the number of bytes processed whether the data is stored in BigQuery or in an external data source such as Google Cloud Storage, Google Drive, or Google Cloud Bigtable.

So you get 1TB of free processing per month of data, after which you would start getting billed.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you explicitly save to a file, R stores the data in memory.  Because of the way sessions work, however, RStudio will basically keep a copy of the session unless you tell it not to, which is why it asks you if you want to save your session when you exit of switch projects.  What you should do to be sure of not storing anything is when you are done for the day (or whatever) use the broom icon in the Environment tab to delete everything in the environment. Or you can individually delete a data frame or other object `rm(obj)`  or go to the environment window and change "list" to "grid" and select individual objects to remove.  See this [How do I clear only a few specific objects from the workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761992/how-do-i-clear-only-a-few-specific-objects-from-the-workspace)  which addresses this part of my answer (but this is not a duplicate question).