# Removing Files from Global Environment with a Certain Pattern

Tags: r

I have these files in my global environment:

```
 x <- sapply(sapply(ls(), get), is.data.frame)
 n = names(x)[(x==TRUE)] 

 n

 [1] "sample_1"  "sample_10" "sample_2"  "sample_3"  "sample_4"  "sample_5"  "sample_6"  "sample_7"  "sample_8"  "sample_9"  "table_i"
```

I want to remove all files that start with "samp". I found the this code that can do this ([How do I clear only a few specific objects from the workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761992/how-do-i-clear-only-a-few-specific-objects-from-the-workspace)):

```
rm(list = apropos("samp_"))
```

Now, I want to learn how to do the same thing using a different way. I found another way to find out all files in the global environment that start with "samp":

```
 nn = grep("samp", n, value = TRUE)  

 [1] "sample_1"  "sample_10" "sample_2"  "sample_3"  "sample_4"  "sample_5"  "sample_6"  "sample_7"  "sample_8"  "sample_9"
```

Then, I tried to delete these files:

```
for (file in nn){
    nn[i] <- NULL
  }

do.call(file.remove, list(nn))
```

- I think I am missing something here - can someone please show me how to correct this?

Thank you!

Comment: `file.remove` will delete files from your computer rather than from the global environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of `pattern` inside of the remove function:

```
rm(list = ls(pattern = "^samp"))
```

Or using `grep`:

```
rm(list = grep("^samp", ls(), value = TRUE))
```